# 'ReferenceError: web3 is not defined on a client side application

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am building a client side web application with web3js and metamask. I have the web3 javascript file in a folder and metamask installed on firefox. I included the web3 file with a HTML script tag and made the metamask connection in the code.

Nevertheless, I keep getting the error "ReferenceError: web3 is not defined"

Can someone please help me with this or how to connect web3 and metamask for client side applications?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/web3.min.js"></script>


        window.addEventListener('load', function() {

            if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
                web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
            } else {
             // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
                web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://10.50.0.3:22000"));
            }

            // Now you can start your app & access web3 freely:
            startApp();

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

replace if condition with below snippet:

```
let web3
if(typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.web3 !== 'undefined'){
  //We are in the browser and metamask is running
  web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
}
```

since metamask will inject web3 object and bind to window variable